# How to set a range for TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, timepicker

For example, I want the TimePicker only displays the time after current time or within the next 12 hours， how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look this example.In this peace of code, I am controlling the max and min date. Maybe you can modify this code to control the max and min time (not date). I think you are not going to have too many problems modifying this code.

For Android version above to Honeycom we can use the method setMinDate(). For older versions we control the max and min when the user try to modify the date.

```
// Calendar
this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
this.datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.xxxxx);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // (picker is a DatePicker)
    this.datePicker.setMinDate(this.calendar.getTimeInMillis());
} else {
    final int minYear = this.calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int minMonth = this.calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int minDay = this.calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    this.datePicker.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay,
        new OnDateChangedListener() {

            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int month, int day) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, month, day);

                if (calendar.after(newDate)) {
                    view.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay, this);
                }
            }
        });
   Log.w(TAG, "API Level < 11 so not restricting date range...");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems that this method works no very well, finally i write a new wigdet to implement this..

Comment: quoting *"finally i write a new wigdet to implement this"* comment of @KarelCF  . if you have a working code now , can you post it ? so other might find it useful